# Append Array Values To List Items

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to output an array of items to a list. The problems is when I click submit it's adding all the array items to each list item instead of one each time.

JSFIDDLE:
https://jsfiddle.net/b7Lwbrof/

Thanks!

```
var itemList = [];
var container = document.getElementById('container');

// On click
document.getElementById('submit').addEventListener("click", function(){
    var itemValue = document.getElementById('itemValue').value;

    // Push to array
    itemList.push(itemValue);

    // Append to List
    for(i=0; i<itemList.length; i++) {
        var items = document.createElement("li");
        document.getElementById('container').appendChild(items);
        items.innerHTML = itemList[i];
    }
})
```

Comment: you could either append the last item to the list, or rewrite the whole list.

Comment: @NinaScholz: his logic aims to `rewrite the whole list.` .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need loop then, just append the item after it has been push to the itemList.

```
document.getElementById('submit').addEventListener("click", function(){
    var itemValue = document.getElementById('itemValue').value;

    // Push to array
    itemList.push(itemValue);

    // Append to List
     var items = document.createElement("li");
     document.getElementById('container').appendChild(items);
     items.innerHTML = itemList[itemList.length-1];
})
```

Answer (score 2):

```
items.innerHTML = itemList[itemList.length - 1] // get the last
```

and NOT

```
items.innerHTML = itemList[i]
```

---

And **remove the loop** as @digit said  .

Fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/abdennour/b7Lwbrof/1/)